# How to retain the DropDownList selected input text during the Post back and creation of dynamic web controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, web-controls, servercontrols

I am able to generate few dynamic web controls based on the DropDownList_SelectedValue.

The problem is that the input text which is selected is not retained in the main DropDownList but after postback it chooses the text which is the first in a list of index similar to the datatype of the initial selected value.

Databounded DropDownList:

```
COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  

a            decimal
b            decimal
c            decimal
d            int
e            int
f            varchar
g            varchar
h            varchar
i            varchar
j            varchar
```

If i select j from My DropDownList after post back it retains g as my DDL input text. How to retain j itself after postback.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="column_list_for_filter" DataTextField="COLUMN_NAME" DataValueField="DATA_TYPE" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="column_list_for_filter" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS 'All_Columns', DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'RESULT')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# Code:

```
private void BindDropDownLists()
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in DynamicPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is DropDownList)
            {
                (ctl as DropDownList).DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         {
             BindDropDownLists();

         }
         else
         {
             createdynamiccontrols_decimal();
         }

         if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue == "decimal")
         {
             createdynamiccontrols_decimal();
         }

         if (DropDownList5.SelectedValue == "varchar")
         {
             createdynamiccontrols_varchar();
         }
     }

protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //How to Proceed              
     }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           //How to Proceed
        }

     }
```

Comment: Try to set the selected value into a session. When post back, set the selected value by using the session created.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["DDLValue"] = dropdownlist.SelectedValue;    
 }
```

On page load, get the session and set it to drop down list if it is not NULL:

```
if(Session["DDLValue"] != null)
{
    dropdownlist.SelectedValue = Session["DDLValue"].ToString();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @ Newbie: It doesn't works it always takes the first decimal value in the list of index. How to retain the selected value of decimal datatype or specific datatype.

Comment: @ Newbie: I am beginner to .NET framework and C#. Java scripts i am not comfortable. Need solution in C# ASP.NET only.